# Determine SQL Server components installed

Tags: windows-10, sql-server-2017

I have been given a laptop running on Windows 10 (this is my first experience of windows 10) and SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition is installed.  How can I determine what components are installed with the SQL Server please?  I need to know if the Report Builder or Reporting Services tools are setup.  If not can they easily be added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that in the SQL Server installation centre there is a component to show all installed components.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/validate-a-sql-server-installation